# Solution for $|z+3-4i|\leq5$ modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Here's my solution :
\begin{align} 
&|z+3-4i|\leqq 5\\
&|x+3+(y-4)i|\leqq 5\\
&\sqrt{(x+3)^2+(y-4)^2)}\leqq 5\\   
&(x+3)^2+(y-4)^2)\leqq 25
\end{align}
And is now drawing a circle with $x=-3, y=4$ and $r=5$.
My answer will be all numbers lying on or inside the circle, is this a good answer?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes, your answer is *correct*.

Long Answer: Your answer could be more *formal* ("*good answer*"), in the sense that you could reference the inequality as an (representation)

> **circular area in the complex plane, bounded by $r = 5$ and centred at $(x, y) = (-3, 4)$**

rather than just

> *a circle with $x = −3, y = 4$ and $r = 5$*

---

Furthermore, one could clarify the following:

> "*all numbers lying on or inside the circle*"

with

> **Given** $z = x + yi$, **then all possible** $(x, y)$ **are satisfied by/within** $(x + 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 \le 25$